# What is the most optimal approach for a rate lookup in single SQL select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-join

I am working on a platform that executes SQL select statements to get data for reporting.

I need to write a query that returns all columns from table `A`, plus a few calculated columns.
The calculated columns are multiplications with a single column from table `B`, repeated few times for different `B` rows, identified with a constant, i.e.

```
SELECT 
  A.Column1, 
  A.Column2, 
  A.Column1 * B1.Rate as Column1_Rate1,
  A.Column2 * B1.Rate as Column2_Rate1,
  A.Column1 * B2.Rate as Column1_Rate2,
  A.Column2 * B2.Rate as Column2_Rate2
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TabelB B1 on B1.ID = 'ID1'
LEFT JOIN TabelB B2 on B2.ID = 'ID2'
```

My question is - what would be the most optimal way to write such a query, considering that:
I am working with MSSQL 2019.
I cannot use a stored procedure (if I could, I would move rate lookup into a separate statement, which I think would be the most optimal).
The query will become a sub-query of another select statement, that will only pick a subset of columns from it, e.g.

```
SELECT Column1, Column1_Rate1 FROM (^ABOVE QUERY^)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can advice next approach:
Because table of rates not linked to data table you can grab rates by one query and use cross join after that:

```
SELECT 
  A.Column1, 
  A.Column2, 
  A.Column1 * Rate1 as Column1_Rate1,
  A.Column2 * Rate1 as Column2_Rate1,
  A.Column1 * Rate2 as Column1_Rate2,
  A.Column2 * Rate2 as Column2_Rate2
FROM TableA A
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 
      MIN(CASE WHEN ID = 'ID1' THEN Rate END) Rate1,
      MIN(CASE WHEN ID = 'ID2' THEN Rate END) Rate2
  FROM TableB WHERE ID IN ('ID1', 'ID2')
) Rates
```

[Test MS SQL 2019 queries online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/084aaa42ef9be80a7944df453a30084c/)

or using [CTE](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/5358d12665942c595dc23267f1bd017e/):

```
WITH Rates AS (
  SELECT 
      MIN(CASE WHEN ID = 'ID1' THEN Rate END) Rate1,
      MIN(CASE WHEN ID = 'ID2' THEN Rate END) Rate2
  FROM TableB WHERE ID IN ('ID1', 'ID2')
) SELECT 
  A.Column1, 
  A.Column2, 
  A.Column1 * Rate1 as Column1_Rate1,
  A.Column2 * Rate1 as Column2_Rate1,
  A.Column1 * Rate2 as Column1_Rate2,
  A.Column2 * Rate2 as Column2_Rate2
FROM Rates, TableA A;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look how that compares

Comment: It is a bad habit to use [old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Here your cross-join was intentional but the old-style remains a bad habit. Just use "CROSS JOIN" like you did in the first example.